# Kafka Channel name with a 'period' in Quarkus application

Tags: java, quarkus, smallrye, quarkus-kafka

While I am playing with  repo [kafka-quickstart](https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus-quickstarts/tree/main/kafka-quickstart) , I noticed that if I add a period to the channel name quarkus is failing to start. The channel name in the github repo is 'quotes' and I changed it to 'quotes.ch' all over the occurrences.

the properties file entry is changed to 
mp.messaging.outgoing.**quotes.ch**.value.serializer=io.quarkus.kafka.client.serialization.ObjectMapperSerializer

The outgoing annotation with channel name "quotes.ch" in QuotesProcessor
and the channel annotation with "quotes.ch" in QuotesResource

The processor application failed to start with below exception :: How to handle such names in quarkus?

Thread [39m [38;5;188m) [39m [38;5;151mFailed to start application (with profile dev) [39m [38;5;203m: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: SRMSG00071: **Invalid channel configuration -  the `connector` attribute must be set for channel `quotes`**
at io.smallrye.reactive.messaging.providers.impl.ConnectorConfig.lambda$new$0(ConnectorConfig.java:50)
at java.base/java.util.Optional.orElseThrow(Optional.java:403)
at io.smallrye.reactive.messaging.providers.impl.ConnectorConfig.lambda$new$1(ConnectorConfig.java:50)
at java.base/java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:364)
at io.smallrye.reactive.messaging.providers.impl.ConnectorConfig.(ConnectorConfig.java:49)
at io.smallrye.reactive.messaging.providers.impl.ConfiguredChannelFactory.lambda$extractConfigurationFor$0(ConfiguredChannelFactory.java:85)
at java.base/java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75)
at io.smallrye.reactive.messaging.providers.impl.ConfiguredChannelFactory.extractConfigurationFor(ConfiguredChannelFactory.java:74)

**UPDATE:::**
This problem/bug is fixed in https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/pull/25490

Comment: Can you try adding quotes around the channel name? (I do recognize there's too many "quotes" here... :-) ) Like this: `mp.messaging.outgoing."quotes.ch".value.serializer=io.quarkus.kafka.client.serialization.ObjectMapperSerializer`

Comment: @Ladicek: I tried "quotes.ch" and 'quotes.ch' but facing the same problem.           
 Invalid channel configuration -  the `connector` attribute must be set for channel `quotes`

Comment: @Ladicek:                                                                                                                                I added the connector property mp.messaging.outgoing."quotes.ch".connector=smallrye-kafka  didnt fix the problem

Comment: Okay, then that's probably a bug. SmallRye Reactive Messaging does manipulate the configuration properties quite a bit and probably doesn't support the quotation syntax. I'd suggest to file an issue either in SmallRye Reactive Messaging (https://github.com/smallrye/smallrye-reactive-messaging/) or in Quarkus.

Comment: Yes, sounds like a bug in the quarkus integration. We have tests for "pure" smallrye.

Comment: Created new issue to quarkus, https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/25437

Answer (score 0):

you need update your application.properties like a this

```
# Configurazione incoming quotes Kafka topic for Channel
mp.messaging.incoming.quotes.connector=smallrye-kafka
mp.messaging.incoming.quotes.topic=quotes
mp.messaging.incoming.quotes.auto.offset.reset=earliest
```

after configuring correctly kafka you can use

```java
@Channel("quotes")...
```

Official documentation:
more info for your use case here https://quarkus.io/guides/kafka-reactive-getting-started
and other example here https://quarkus.io/blog/getting-started-kafka/